# How can I access a data repeater's item by index instead of explicit name?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, windows, vb.net

Right now I'm using the following code in my markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TheName" runat="server" Value=<%#Eval("SpeakerName")%> />
```

I would like to use:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TheName" runat="server" Value=<%#Eval(0)%> />
```

I would like to be able to call it by index instead of explicitly by "SpeakerName". Is there a way to do this in ASP.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TheName" runat="server" Value=<%# Eval("[0]") %> />
```